# NStreeController - NSoutlineView get cell binding object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

I have the following scenario in a `NSoutlineView`:

```
ParentObject            [checkbox]
  - ChildObject 1       [checkbox]
  - ChildObject 2       [checkbox]
```

Each checkbox has a binding set up to a bool value of the respective object in a `NSTreeController`. When a user selects the parentObject checkbox, the respective children checkboxes should also be set. However, when a child object checkbox is set, the parent checkbox should not be affected. I cannot seem to get the parent functionality working properly.

My current attempted solution to the problem is:
when the checkbox is set call:

```
-(IBAction)CheckSelected:(NSButtonCell *)sender 
 {
     // Somehow access the cells bound object in the NSTreeController ?????
 }
```

However from my research I have not been able to find a way to get access to the cell's respective object in the `NSTreeController`.

Any insight on the problem would be greatly appreciated. I feel like this is a common problem that people would run into using an NStreeController and I am curious if I am taking the proper approach.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The checkboxes shouldn’t be set up to call an action—they should be bound to a property, like, say, “isChecked”.

In your ParentObject you’ll have code similar to:

```
- (void)setIsChecked:(BOOL)isChecked;
{
    _isChecked = isChecked;
    for (ChildObject *childObject in self.children)
        childObject.isChecked = isChecked;
}
```

Since the children’s checkboxes are also bound, the children’s new state will be reflected in the outline view immediately.